# Send to more than one email address in Marketing cloud journey builder

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, email-studio

I have built a journey where i sent an email to the contacts that are loaded via csv file, but then i need to send a email to the manager of that contacts if they click in one link present in the email.

So, in the data extension i have the contact email, and their managers email. How can i alter the sends between emails?

Comment: You can’t have two emails to one subscriber key (this would be the case, if both your email addresses share the same row in your sendable DE)

Comment: The link you’re tracking - you can put a CloudPage between the email and that final link, so that when they click it first opens the CloudPage and from there it instantly redirects to your destination link. And on that CloudPage you can include a script to trigger an email to the manager. This would happen instantly and without any impact on what the person sees when they click the link in email.